# Print first 100 values using cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to print the first 100 values for a field using cursor.I get an ORA-06550 error here though.Could someone tell me what is that I am missing .

```
Declare 
  BG_TOTAL number;

  cursor c1 is 
    select BG_ID 
      from <tablename>;

  Type BG_TAB_TYPE is table of  c1%ROWTYPE;

  BG_LIST BG_TAB_TYPE;

Begin
  open c1;
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO BG_LIST;

  close c1;

   for i in 1..c1.count    
   loop
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c1(i).BG_ID);
   End loop;  
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop through the nested table to which you bulk-collected records, not through the cursor. This is the corrected code:

```
Declare 
  BG_TOTAL number;

  cursor c1 is 
    select BG_ID 
      from my_Tab524;

  Type BG_TAB_TYPE is table of  c1%ROWTYPE;

  BG_LIST BG_TAB_TYPE;

Begin
  open c1;
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO BG_LIST;

  close c1;

   for i in 1..BG_LIST.count    
   loop
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(BG_LIST(i).BG_ID);
     EXIT WHEN i = 10;
   End loop;  
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. But then how do you specify the count of records you want to print to. Say I just want to print first 10.

Comment: @Nathan Limit the number of rows returned from the cursor. Or bulk collect only 10 of them. Or specify the 1..10 in your loop (watch out for a case when the query will return less than 10 records), or use a counter in your loop and increase it by 1 after each record is printed, and EXIT WHEN your_counter > 10. Added the counter.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to use `bulk collect` with a `limit`.

This nicely separates the content, the limitation and the processing. The separation might not be an issue in your case but I have found this useful every now an then (helps me to write more modular code that's easy to test).

```
declare
  -- data content
  cursor tables_c is select * from all_tables;
  type table_list_t is table of tables_c%rowtype;

  v_table_list table_list_t;
begin
  open tables_c;

  -- limiting the data set
  fetch tables_c bulk collect into v_table_list limit 8;

  -- processing
  for i in 1 .. v_table_list.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_table_list(i).table_name);
  end loop;

  close tables_c;
end;
/
```